# How to pass data between multiple pages from one page in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, mongoose, react-router

in the homepage i am getting data from api. I want to pass this data to multiple pages. How can i do that?

This is the homepage where i get the data from mapping the array data i got from api

Homepage.js

```
import './Homepage.css'
import banner from '../images/ecom.png'
import img1 from '../images/beigehoodie.jpg'
import { Link , useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect } from "react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Homepage = () => {
    const [allitems, setAllitems] = useState([])

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const getItems = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getitem`);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAllitems(response.data.item);
            console.log("response" , response.item)
            console.log("allitems  ", allitems)
        } else {
           console.log("Error loading items")
        }
    }

  

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems()
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
         

            <div>
                <img className='banner' src={banner} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Featured Products</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="carouselExample" className="carousel slide">
                <div className="carousel-inner">
                    <div className="carousel-item active">
                        <div className='row'>
                            
                        {allitems.map((item)=>{
                            console.log("allitems  ", allitems)

                                
                            
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12' key={item._id}>
                                <div className="card">
                                    <img src={item.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                            <h5 className="card-title">{item.name}</h5>
                                            <p>{item.price}</p>
                                            <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>

                                            <button type="button" onClick={
                                                navigate('/products')
                                               
                                            } className="btn btn-warning">Add to cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>  
                                                
                
                   
                    </div>
                    )})}
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>    
                <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>

        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Homepage
```

This is the product page where i will display data from homepage. After clicking Add to cart it should send the image , name , price and description data to product page

Product.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect } from "react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import img1 from '../images/beigehoodie.jpg'

const Product = () => {

    const CONFIG_OBJ = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    }
    const [allreview, setAllReview] = useState([])

    const location = useLocation()

    const getReview = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getreview`, CONFIG_OBJ);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAllReview(response.data.review);
            console.log("address", response.data.review)
        } else {
            console.log("Error loading items")
        }
    }
    console.log("location state " , location.state)
    console.log("location image" , location.state)

    useEffect(() => {
        getReview()
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="container login-container">
            <div className="row d-flex">
                                
            
                           
                            <div className="col-md-7 col-sm-12 ">
              
                            <img src={img1} className="instagram" width='400px' height='400px' />
                            {console.log("imageP" , location.state)}
                        </div>
        
                        <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12 ">
                            <div className="card shadow">
                                <div className='col-md-12 text-center'>
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="card-header">
                                        
                                        </div>
                                        <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                                            <li className="list-group-item">Rating</li>
                                            <li className="list-group-item">Price</li>
                                            <li className="list-group-item">Description</li>
                                            <a href="#" className="btn btn-warning">Add to cart</a>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-body px-5">
                        
        
                                </div>
                            </div>

                       
         </div>

           
            </div>
            <h2>Reviews</h2>
            <div>
            {allreview.map((review) => {

return (
    <div>
                <span className="border border-warning-subtle">
                    <table className="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <td>{review.customer.fullName}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Rating</th>
                                <td>{review.star}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Review</th>
                                <td>{review.reviewText}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </div>    

)

})}
</div>
            <h2>Write a review</h2>
            <p>Ratings</p>
            <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

            <form>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Write review</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
                </div>
                </form>
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-warning">Submit</a>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

After i get data in product page i want to share that data to the checkout page. How can i share that?

Checkout.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect } from "react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Checkout = () => {
    const CONFIG_OBJ = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    }

    const [alladdress, setAllAddress] = useState([])
    const [checkout, setCheckout] = useState([])

    const getAddress = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getaddress`, CONFIG_OBJ);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAllAddress(response.data.address);
            console.log("address", response.data.address)
        } else {
            console.log("Error loading items")
        }
    }

    const getCheckout = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getcheckout`, CONFIG_OBJ);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            setCheckout(response.data.checkout);
            console.log("checkout", response.data.checkout)
        } else {
            console.log("Error loading items")
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAddress()
        getCheckout()
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="container login-container">
            <div className="row">


                <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-12 justify-content-left" >
                    {alladdress.map((add) => {

                        return (
                            <div>
                                <div className="card" key={add._id} >
                                    <div className="card-body justify-content-left">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">Shipping</h5>
                                        <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-body-secondary">Name: {add.fullName}</h6>
                                        {console.log("address 3", add.address)}
                                        <p className="card-text">Address: {add.address},{add.city},{add.postalcode},{add.country}</p>
                                        <a href="#" className="card-link">Edit</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        )

                    })}


                    <div className="card" >
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Payment</h5>
                            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-body-secondary">Card subtitle</h6>
                            <p className="card-text">Method- Paypal</p>
                            <a href="#" className="card-link">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-12 ">
                    <div className="card shadow">
                        <div className='col-md-12 text-center'>
                            {checkout.map((checkout) => {
                                    var x = (parseInt(checkout.quantity) * parseInt(checkout.amount))
                                return (
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="card-header">
                                            <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <table className="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Items</th>
                                <td>{x}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Shipping</th>
                                <td>$0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Tax</th>
                                <td>$10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <td>{x + 10}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <a href="#" className="btn btn-warning">Place order</a>
                                    </div>
                                    
                            ) })}
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body px-5">


                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many different "data passing" mechanisms available in React.

Recognize that a React app is a "tree of components" where the root component (typically `<App>`) is the top of the tree and all other components are descendents.

Which mechanism is correct (or valid) for your app depends a bit on how you have constructed your tree of components.  Another consideration is how you are navigating from one page to another.

If your page flow is always Home >> Product >> Checkout then you could simply pass the data from one screen to the next.  But if your users might follow other flows (including "going back" via the Back button), then passing data from page to page gets very complicated.

Instead, one approach it to use some type of data caching where information is stored "in the tree" and you can fetch that data from any "descendents" below that cache.

For example your `App.jsx` might have:

```
return (
  <DataCacheProvider>
    <Routes>
      <Route "homepage" />
      <Route "product" />
      <Route "checkout" />
    </Routes>
  </DataCacheProvider>
);
```

Where `<DataCacheProvider>` could be a complex "state management" system such as Redux, MobX, Zustrand....or a less complicated solution such as using React's [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

Any component that is a descendent of `<DataCacheProvider>` would use the necessary API to get the value stored in the Provider.  No need to "pass the value around"...simply stick the value into the DataCacheProvider when the data is fetched, then anywhere you need to use that data you'd pull it out of the cache provider.

For example, if using the Context API you would use the `useContext(DataCacheContext)` anywhere in the tree nested inside the `<DataCacheProvider>....</DataCacheProvider>` tags to get whatever value was stored in the cache.

Personally, I am a fan of starting simple (Context API) and only bringing in a more complex solution once I have ***proven*** that I need it.

Comment: from product it goes to 2 different pages and then to the checkout page. How can i do in this case?

Comment: Use the Context API.  Then any page below the `<DataCacheProvider>` could use the hook `useContext(DataCacheContext)` to get values out of that cache.  This is a nearly identical pattern to what you would do if you used one of the "state management" systems I listed above.